# Powershell- match split and replace based on index

Tags: powershell, replace, substring, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a file

```
AB*00*Name1First*Name1Last*test
BC*JCB*P1*Church St*Texas
CD*02*83*XY*Fax*LM*KY
EF*12*Code1*TX*1234*RJ
```

I need to replace the 5th element in the CD segment alone from LM to ET in each of the file in the folder. Element delimiter is * as mentioned in the above sample file content. I am new to PowerShell and tried a code as below but unfortunately it is not giving desired results. Can any of you please provide some help?

```
foreach($xfile in $inputfolder)
{
If ($_ match "^CD\*")
{
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($xfile).replace(($_.split("*")[5],"ET") | Set-Content $xfile
}
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($xfile),((Get-Content $xfile -join("~")))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a slightly different way to get there ... [*grin*] what it does ...

- fakes reading in a test file
  when ready to do this for real, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and use `Get-Content`.
- sets the constants
- iterates thru the imported text file lines
- checks for a line that starts with the target pattern
- if found ...
  == escapes the old value with `[regex]::Escape()` to deal with the asterisks
  == replaces the escaped old value with the new value
  == outputs the new version of that line
- if NOT found, outputs the line as-is
- stores all the lines into the `$OutStuff` var
- displays that on screen

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a plain text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
AB*00*Name1First*Name1Last*test
BC*JCB*P1*Church St*Texas
CD*02*83*XY*Fax*LM*KY
EF*12*Code1*TX*1234*RJ
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a plain text file

$TargetLineStart = 'CD*'
$OldValue = '*LM*'
$NewValue = '*ET*'
$OutStuff = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    if ($IS_Item.StartsWith($TargetLineStart))
        {
        $IS_Item -replace [regex]::Escape($OldValue), $NewValue
        }
        else
        {
        $IS_Item
        }
    }

$OutStuff
```

output ...

```
AB*00*Name1First*Name1Last*test
BC*JCB*P1*Church St*Texas
CD*02*83*XY*Fax*ET*KY
EF*12*Code1*TX*1234*RJ
```

i will leave saving that to a new file [or overwriting the old one] to the user. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you. But how do I save it as a file in the original format after replacing an element in a line ?

Comment: @ACCADemyACCADemy - you use one of the "save to file" cmdlets. [*grin*] i would use `$OutStuff | Set-Content -Path $NewFileName` for that.

Comment: @ACCADemyACCADemy - you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You could capture all that comes before the match in group 1, and match LM.

In the replacement use `$1ET`

```
^(CD*(?:[^*\r\n]+\*){5})LM\b
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28CD*%28%3f%3a%5b%5e*%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%5c*%29%7b5%7d%29LM%5cb&i=AB*00*Name1First*Name1Last*test%0d%0aBC*JCB*P1*Church+St*Texas%0d%0aCD*02*83*XY*Fax*LM*KY%0d%0aEF*12*Code1*TX*1234*RJ&r=%241ET&o=m)

If you don't want to match LM literally, you could also match any other char than `*` or a newline.

```
^(CD*(?:[^*\r\n]+\*){5})[^*\r\n]+\b
```

[image]

Replace example

```
$allText = Get-Content -Raw file.txt
$allText -replace '(?m)^(CD*(?:[^*\r\n]+\*){5})LM\b','$1ET'
```

Output

```
AB*00*Name1First*Name1Last*test
BC*JCB*P1*Church St*Texas
CD*02*83*XY*Fax*ET*KY
EF*12*Code1*TX*1234*RJ
```